# React props={this.refs.something} undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<Modal/>` component in my APP.

Modal has two methods `show()` and `hide()` where I change the state of the component.

In my App I have:

```
<App>
   <Modal ref="modal"/>
   <Menu openModal={this.refs.modal.show}/>
</App>
```

But inside the Menu `this.props.openModal` is undefined.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd recomend you to use props on Modal to show or hide it. Using refs is antipattern in most cases, and especially for that kind of imperative calls. So on openModal you change state to {show: true} and then pass show={this.state.show} to Modal.

Comment: I'm not sure probably you have typo, instead of `this.refs.modal.show` should be `this.refs.modal`

Comment: inside the menu  i have an element where i want to trigger the modal open, how can i achieve this right way?

Comment: @The, show is the method of the modal class, where I open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because at the time of rendering, *this.refs.modal* hasn't been defined yet.

What you should do is have some state on the App component, then a callback to change that state, which gets passed down to the Modal as a prop.

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {modalOpen: false};
},
setModalOpen: function(open) {
    this.setState({modalOpen: false});
}
...
render: function () {
    return (
        <App>
            <Modal open={this.state.modalOpen} setOpen={this.setModalOpen}/>
            <Menu openModal={this.setModalOpen}/>
        </App>
    );
}
```

You can then read the state of the modal as a prop, but note also that the Modal component should use the callback to set the state on the App component and only use the prop, not override it with it's own internal state.